# Material UI TextField not displaying properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am using react with Material UI. TextField is not working as expected

[Picture of MUI TextField not working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHJhb.png)

I also removed all css to check if some css was interfering with the textfield but that was not the case. Please help me debug this issue. Here is the code for it. Thank you!

```
<Grid
        container
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
      >
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <TextField
            label={question.qs_label}
            placeholder={question.qs_statement}
            onChange={(e) => setAnswer(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            disabled={answer.length === 0}
            onClick={() => {
              console.log(answer);
              props.go_next();
            }}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a problem with your code, best guess is it is related to your projects setup or a conflict with other libraries.   Also make sure that he @mui/material and @emotion packages are installed with the correct versions: npm install @mui/material@latest @emotion/react@latest @emotion/styled@latest

Also make sure there are no duplicate packages installed

Comment: @BOB Thanks for your reply. I have checked these things and updated mui. But still, I got the same issue. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions

Comment: The next step would be to start with a fresh install, recreate just that part with only the material ui stuff installed... without seeing the full install, I am not going to be of much further help.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that